# php extracting object relatives

Tags: php, object

I have two objects that come from DB queries. I've limited them to the minimum I need for the view. They look like this :

```
array(189) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#31 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "187"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Something"
  }
}

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#337 (10) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["for"]=>
    string(3) "187"
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm running the second object in a foreach loop. I'd like to reference "for" to to the "id" of the first, and return the "name", resulting "Something". My attempt to at least use the index failed, but I'd like to avoid using the index either way.

I want to use the value "for" of my second object, link it to the "id" of my first object, and output the matching "name", in my case "Something". How do I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. Maybe show some pseudo code with the desired result?

Comment: Sounds like you want to walk through the first array and find the object with id=187 so you can access it's other properties? Unless the keys of the first array are the object's id numbers (not currently), you will need to loop through each item and test its id property until you find the one you want.

Comment: Thank you. looping through each item would be slow wouldn't it? I think it would be better to prepare the data beforehand, as in, before sending it to my view, correct?

Comment: @user1732521 depends on how many data you have there but if you just want the name of a single id then you just need to iterate once if u need the name of all matched ids then u will need to iterate with 2 foreach's.

Comment: I should have between 300 and 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like you want find the object from the first array with `id` equal to `"187"` so you can access it's other properties?

Unless the keys of the first array are the object's id numbers (not currently), you will need to loop through each item of the first array and test its `id` property until you find the one you want. In other words, a nested loop.

Perhaps it is better to restructure the first array. The alternative is to create the first array keyed on the `id` instead of autogenerated sequential keys. This would allow you to easily access the item you want without conducting a search (e.g., `$first[$id]['name']`). The appropriate approach would depend on how often this lookup operation needs to be conducted and the size of the arrays.

If `id` is guarantted to be unique, then something like this could pre-process the array so it is keyed on the `id` property:

```
// $array189 is the first array from your question
$first = array();
foreach ($array189 as $item) {
    $first[ $item->id ] = $item;
}
unset($array189);
```

Comment: According to his array size, index and id's they don't match so I don't think that would work.

Comment: @Prix Oops, corrected `$item['id']` to `$item->id`. This will build a new array, using the `id` property of each item as the key (and the item itself as the value). Assuming all items have an `id` and there are no duplicates, I don't see the issue.

Comment: Yes, that would work, and be probably faster than 2 loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. The best way would be to restructure the array prior to using it. Right now I'll go with the quick dual foreach route, but I'll switch to restructuring later in production! However, I'll avoid using the index for sure. Not sure which one to choose as a best answer really.